# How do I clear gnome-calculator history?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, calculator

How do I clear gnome calculator history? Like in terminal, we can press Ctrl L to clear, but what about calculator? I also don't see a clear button?

[image]

Comment: Did you try entering "reset"?

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson - no, it won't work. `Del` used to reset the calc (confirmed by [older man pages](https://manned.org/gnome-calculator/0b340d93)) but it doesn't work anymore. I think it was around 3.12 that they fubar-ed the whole gtk keyboard shortcuts module... whether this is related to that or it's a bug in calc, I don't know...

Comment: Nah none of them work Dx

Comment: What a horrible user experience that we need to ask how to do something so trivial...

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> clears the calculator history (tested on Ubuntu 19.10 and Fedora 28).

This is documented in the shortcuts screen available from the menu:

[image: List of calculator shortcuts]